How to modify Ctrl Y shortcut to redo not to delete in PL/SQL developer
It is very annoying that I cannot redo using CTRL + Y in PL SQL developer like I normally would anywhere else. Instead it deleted the whole line. I tried looking for shortcuts modification in preferences but it seems it is impossible to modify shortcuts for this program?

I am able to see/change shorcuts by: Tools->Preferences->User Interface->Key Configuration. Don't you have this functionality? Which PL/SQL developer version do you have?

Yes, I was able to find it now. Thank you. I had to go to Preferences -> User Interface->Key Configuration. No tools tab or button needed.
